# Find the length of the diagonal of a parallelogram given sides and angle between side and diagonal

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, quadrilateral

The longer side of a parallelogram is 10 cm and shorter is 6 cm. If the longer diagonal makes an angle 30 degrees with the longer side, find the length of the longer diagonal.

In this question let $AB=10$ & $BC=6$.
Height can be determined by 
$ab\sin\theta = base \times height$
Therefore height = 3.

If BM is height then we can find the distance MC (by Pythagoras theorem) as $3\sqrt 3$
Again using Pythagoras' theorem for AEC(ec is height) 
$diagonal^2 = 3^2 +(10+3\sqrt3)^2$

But this is coming out to be wrong. Please let me know if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Note that 30$^{\circ}$ is *not* the angle between the shorter and longer side; it is the angle between the *diagonal* and the longer side.  Therefore, your application of $ab \sin \theta$ to assume a parallelogram area of $30 cm^2$ ($10 cm \cdot 6 cm \cdot \sin 30^{\circ}$) is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 6_x_10_parallelogram_30_deg_diag_and_long]

In the picture shown, $AB = DC = 10$, $BC = AD = 6$, and $\angle BDC = 30^{\circ}$.

Apply the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to $\triangle BDC$.  Then

$$6^2 = d^2 + 10^2 - 2 \cdot d \cdot 10 \cdot \cos 30^{\circ}$$
$$36 = d^2 + 100 - 20d \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$0 = d^2 - 10d\sqrt{3} + 64$$
$$d^2=10d\sqrt{3} + 64$$
$$d=\sqrt{10d\sqrt{3} + 64}$$

Apply the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) to solve for the long diagonal $d$.  You should get two (geometrically valid) roots, although only one of the roots makes $BD$ the **long** diagonal; the other root [makes it the short one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge9AZ.jpg).